# Running su from a system app OR deleting external storage files from a system app

Tags: android, file-io, android-4.4-kitkat, su, android-external-storage

I have been reading some stuff about the new external SD security rules that were introduced in KitKat 4.4, and still can't figure why exactly can't a system application still delete files from the external card (yes, even files that aren't mine, but am I a system app or not)?
The device is rooted. Deleting files using `adb shell` works. From my application, however - it doesn't work (only on the external storage).

Another try I had was to execute "su" from my application, but I am getting: su: uid 1000 not allowed to su.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: The system user is historically unallowed to use sd cards because removing the card will kill any process with an open file handle there.  Your `su` error means you don't have a root-hacked `su`

Comment: Maybe, but some programs, like ES File explorer, DOES manage to see/read/write data directly from the external storage, and even delete files from there (or from different folders there - like my app's files). How did they do it then? is it possible to have such access to the external storage?

Comment: The "system user" and "root" are *entirely* distinct mechanisms.  The first is controlled by the install location or package signatures, the second by unix permission bits (though increasingly constrained by enforcing mode selinux).